# Display sprintf text in uicontrol text MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, uicontrol

This seems like it should be simple. I have a uicontrol of Style text:

```
x_text = uicontrol(f,'Style','text','String','X: ','Position', [10 220 50 20], 'HorizontalAlign','Left','FontName','Monospace','FontSize',12);
```

at some point later, I try to change the text to include a number. I have tried several methods, and anytime i try to use a Format, it fails. E.g.

Works

```
set(x_text, 'String', ['X: ' num2str(State(1))]);
```

Fails

```
set(x_text, 'String', ['X: ' num2str(State(1),'%0.3f')]);
set(x_text, 'String', ['X: ' sprintf('%0.3f',State(1))]);
```

As you might be able to guess, what I want is to set the number of places to the right of the decimal point, as I did above. Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 0):

What about writing it in 2 lines?

```
numStr=num2str(State(1),'%0.3f');
set(x_text, 'String', ['X: ',numStr]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating strings using matrix notation like: `[string1 string2]` *(or with `strcat` routine btw)* is quite dangerous in my opinion and often leads to "strange" behavior.

Prefer always working with `sprintf` only:

```
txt = sprintf('X: %0.3f', State(1));
set(x_text, 'String', txt);
```

Or in single line:

```
set(x_text, 'String', sprintf('X: %0.3f', State(1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

All reasonable suggestions and things I tried. It turns out it was just as simple as making the format '%#.3f', where # is something larger than 0; i.e. the # defines the max number of displayable characters, so it was displaying 0 of them. I changed it to, for example, '%5.3f' and it worked fine.

Thanks for the suggestions.